# understanding JSESSIONID with basic authentication

Tags: spring, servlets, session-cookies, backend, web-frontend

I went through some resources about `JSESSIONID`. They say that HTTP and web-servers are stateless. Ok fine, I know this. But then they say- to add a state to these, sessions are used. And there is a session created `JSESSIONID` by web servers(in java applications). `JSESSIONID` helps web servers to recognize if the request is coming from the same previous user or a new user. But, this created a doubt in me:
For basic authentication(for example), we send username password with each request, along with `JSESSIONID`. So, what additional benefit does `JSESSIONID` adds to that request, if we still need to send credentials with each request. What is the benefit of remembering the client-requests(the idea of using session-cookies)?
Any real-world example, please.

Comment: Because websites don't always require basic authentication, and basic authentication from HTTP authenticates a request, but does not always specify a single user, think for example a passworded internal webapp that also requires user sign on, there may only be one password for the webapp access to get past the basic auth constraint, but then every user is a different session..